# PHP | Simplification of repetitive code using some sort of PHP loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I wonder if you can help me slim down my code.

I've built a bespoke *share* include for a client site. It works fine but I'm sure one of you clever lot can help me to make it less bulky.

I have three share URLs:
`$share_url_facebook`, `$share_url_twitter` and `$share_url_linkedin`.

Each URL is different in its structure and is fairly complex.

I then have the following code:

```
echo '<a href="' . $share_url_facebook . '" title="Share this on facebook">';
echo '<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>';
echo '</a>';
echo '<a href="' . $share_url_twitter . '" title="Share this on twitter">';
echo '<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>';
echo '</a>';
echo '<a href="' . $share_url_linkedin . '" title="Share this on LinkedIn">';
echo '<i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>';
echo '</a>';
```

Is there a way for me to create some sort of loop to prevent the repetition?

---

Based on the accepted solution by @JasonK here is my final(simplified) tested code:

```
$share = [
    'facebook' => [
        'title' => 'Facebook',
        'url'   => 'https://www.facebook.com/'
    ],
    'twitter' => [
        'title' => 'Twitter',
        'url'   => 'https://twitter.com'
    ],
    'linkedin' => [
        'title' => 'LinkedIn',
        'url'   => 'https://linkedin.com'
    ]
];
foreach ($share as $key => $details) {
    echo '<a href="' . $details['url'] . '" title="Share this on ' . $details['title'] . '">';
    echo '<i class="fa fa-' . $key . '"></i>';
    echo '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Different value used so its not repetition

Comment: You would have to create an array containing the 3 variable values `$share_url_???` and `title` and the css class names `fa-????` so you might even end up with more code in an attempt to create this array and then loop over it

Comment: As RiggsFolly said, create an array to store urls. Iterate over the array

Comment: Create indexed array with `$shareBtns = ['socialMediaName' => 'url', ...]` and iterate over that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already suggested; create an array and iterate over it.

```
$social = [
    'facebook' => [
        'title' => 'Facebook'
        'url'   => 'https://facebook.com'
    ],
    'twitter' => [
        'title' => 'Twitter'
        'url'   => 'https://twitter.com'
    ],
    'linkedin' => [
        'title' => 'LinkedIn'
        'url'   => 'https://linkedin.com'
    ]
];

foreach ($social as $key => $details) {
    echo 'Key ' . $key;
    echo 'Title ' . $details['title'];
    echo 'URL ' . $details['url'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array to store "config". Key is a name of service, value is url or variable with url.

After that, you can iterate on this array using foreach.
In foreach you can use echo or other function to output string, or asigne string to variable. I used sprintf to format all string without contacenation and to assigned it to variable http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
$services [
  'facebook' => $share_url_facebook,
  'twitter' => $share_url_twitter
]
$output = '';
foreach ($services as $serviceName => $url) {
    $output += sprintf(
       '<a href="%s" title="Share this on %s"><i class="fa fa-%s"></i></a>', 
       $url, 
       ucfirst($serviceName),
       $serviceName
   );
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Please improve this answer with the intent to educate.

Comment: @mickmackusa I added description but I think the example is quite easy to understand and it self describing idea of this solution.

Comment: Even simple snippets deserve explanation.  Never assume that future readers have complete literacy of a given language.  That `+=` to perform concatenation looks troublesome in php.  It is a good idea to test your codes before posting.  I normally add a demo link with my answers to double check myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is an even shorter solution to this, which uses PHPs dynamic variables and does not force you to create an array with all details.

This way you can remain your old variables. This is especially useful, if they come from a file you didnt write yourself and therefore cant/dont want to change

```
$social = [ 'facebook', 'twitter', 'linkedin' ];
foreach ($social as $site) {
    print '<a href="' . ${'share_url_' . $site} . '" title="Share this on ' . $site . '">';
    print '<i class="fa fa-' . $site . '"></i>';
    print '</a>';
}
```

Comment: This is incredibly useful, thank you. I find this really interesting too:
`${'share_url_' . $site}`

Comment: You can do basically everything inside the curly brackets. Call functions or methods for example. Keep in mind tho, that this can be hard to debug, so use it carefully.

Comment: @morgyface In virtually all cases, "variable variables" are bad advice/practice.  Most programmers dabble in using them for a short while, but only until they realize they are just poor excuses for arrays.  Let me save you a world of strife -- don't use variable variables.